# I need my dates to stay the same when I switch to general formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My excel sheet has all my invoices dates formatted as date. I need to change the formatting to General, but keep the dates the same and not have it changed over to a decimal so I can export the data.

Is there a certain formula to keep my dates in the cells, but switch the formatting?

Thank you!

Comment: You would have to change the dates to the text representation of a date.  Do an internet search "for how dates are stored in Excel" to better understand the issues.

Comment: Why do you need to change the format to General?  Whatever the purpose is for that, there may be another way to accomplish that, which doesn't mess up your dates.

Comment: Because I need to export the file using import wizard and I can't have the column with the dates in it be in date format since it will only take values and not values and dates.

Comment: Are the dates located in random places or placed in the same column?